# Set up Enable Rule in CRM Visual Ribbon Editor

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using the CRM Visual Ribbon Editor to create a custom button which sends all selected emails.  However, since Email is an Activity entity, other activities could be in the user's selection when pressing the button.

Is there is an enable rule that specefies that all selected items are Emails?

If so, how do I use it?

If not, could a custom rule written in JScript work?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do something like this with a custom entity of mine. I needed to enable a button based on the record status.

I think something like this will only really be possible using a custom rule written in JScript that you could use to query the records and see what type they are.

Hope this helps

Comment: Looking through the rules in the drop-down, I figured I'd have to go with JScript.  Thanks for the confirmation (I didn't want to have to write something if it ended up being unnecessary)